# How to copy specific value from one list to another for specific indexes

Tags: java, lambda

```
class Status{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String savedBy;

    //constructor
    //getters and setters
}

class Event{
    private String title;
    private DateTime effectiveDate;
    private Status status;
    //constructor, getter and setters
}
```

Now in the serviceClass, Suppose I have 2 list of events. ListA and ListB
`List<Event> listA` has multiple event in it and `List<Event> listB` has same number of event as listA but the values of the content are either different or empty in listB than in ListA.
Lets say there are 3 event in each list.

```
listA.get(0).getStatus().getId() = 101
listA.get(0).getStatus().getName() = Bruce Wayne

listA.get(1).getStatus().getId() = 202
listA.get(1).getStatus().getName() = Ra Al Ghul

listA.get(2).getStatus().getId() = 303
listA.get(2).getStatus().getName() = Alfred Pennyworth
```

List 2 may or maynot have the same values for "Status.id" but the names are empty

```
listB.get(0).getStatus().getId() = ""
listB.get(1).getStatus().getId() = 700
listB.get(2).getStatus().getId() = 303.
```

- **Question 1**:
  Now I want to be able to copy only the name from listA to ListB if they have same id? That is `list.get(i).getStatus().name`.
  how do I copy the name values (`event.get(i).getStatus.name`)form list A to list B if they have same Id?
- **Question 2**: How do I replace the value of status with both name and id if the id is null in status?

How can I do it with plain Java and with lambda?

I know the basics but looping into objects inside objects that have indexes is very hard

Comment: By the way, class names in Java start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Please share your efforts as well.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... Now I want to be able to copy only the name from listA to ListB if they have same id? That is `list.get(i).getStatus().name`.
> how do I copy the name values (`event.get(i).getStatus.name`)form list A to list B if they have same Id? ..."*

Just replace the value within the class after matching the *id* value.

> *"... How do I replace the value of status with both name and id if the id is null in status? ..."*

You would either need to create a *set* method for the *name* field of the corresponding class, or change the access to *public* or none.

### `for` loop

Here is an example using a `for` loop.

```java
class Z {
    String s;
    int i;

    Z(String s, int i) {
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }
}
List<Z> a = List.of(new Z("A", 1), new Z("B", 2), new Z("C", 3));
List<Z> b = List.of(new Z("", 0), new Z("", 7), new Z("", 3));
int i;
for (Z x : b) {
    i = x.i;
    for (Z y : a) {
        if (i == y.i) {
            x.s = y.s;
            break;
        }
    }
}
b.forEach(x -> System.out.printf("'%s' %d%n", x.s, x.i));
```

Output

```
'' 0
'' 7
'C' 3
```

### `Stream#peek`

> *"... How can I do it with plane java and with lambda? ..."*

You can utilize the *[Stream#peek](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer))* method to modify each object.

```java
b = b.stream()
     .peek(
         x -> {
             int i = x.i;
             for (Z z : a) if (i == z.i) { x.s = z.s; break; }
         })
     .toList();
```

For more info, see [*Java 8 Streams peek() API*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-peek-api) by Attila Fejér on Baeldung.com.